# How to deserialize json and not make multiple instance of the class, in unity 3d and simplejson?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, json-deserialization

I am trying to parse a json or deserialize a json of the following format. Because of brain fart or not--I cant seem to get it to deserialize--basically I would create a class object with the json structure. Now I want to keep updating this object with new data from next json I receive from server call and now I don't want to create a new object every time...how do I do it? What am I missing?

I am doing this in C# (new to it) and Unity 3D, not using any serialization lib, just simplejson and JsonUtility (yes I know it sucks). I have complex inner structure.

```
{
    JsonArray[5] -> more jsonArray inside
    JsonArray[5]
    JsonArray[5]
    JsonArray[5]
    JsonArray[5]
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to understand how the JSON structure looks like and what kind of exception you get whe you say you can't seem to deserialize it.

Comment: It's kind of hard to understand what you're asking, can you paste the code you're using to get that output?

Answer (score 0):

SimpleJson hasn't this feature, you need write your own implemention.

JsonUtility has one, use [JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite.html)